# How can I remove three-dots at the end of usage line in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Python `argparse` keep putting space and three-dots ( `...`) at the end of `usage:` line, example: `usage: program.sh [-h] command [<options>...] ...`. Would it be possible to remove them?

Example code:

```py
def helper():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        "program.py",              
    )
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", metavar="command [<options>...]")
    driver = subparsers.add_parser(
        "driver", help="Example script")
    driver.add_argument("--bn", type=int, default=0, help="Block number to start fetch blocks from")
    return parser
```

Output:

```sh
$ ./program.sh --help
usage: program.sh [-h] command [<options>...] ...
```

Comment: What's the usage without the metavar?

Comment: @hpaulj I get the same output, instead `usage: program.sh [-h] {driver} ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer: you could write your own usage summary:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    "program.py",                  
    usage="usage: %(prog)s [-h] command [<options>...]",
)
```

---

However, there is something that does not make sense to me.

The `...` is caused by using subparsers. There is usually one subparser per command, for example: 3 commands, i.e. 3 subparsers:

```
Usage:
myprog cmd1 [options and args specific for cmd1]
myprog cmd2 [different options and args for cmd2]
myprog cmd3 [yet another set of options and args]
```

And that can be hardly summarized in one line except with:

```
Usage: myprog command ...
```

unless you are not using any options and args for the commands, which means there is nothing to parse.

So, if you want to get rid of the trailing `...` and still have a valid usage synopsis, you probably do not need subparsers at all.

Comment: I was using option for my command forget to write into my question. Additional `driver.add_argument()` is updated in my question

Answer (score 1):

That usage is produced by the implied `nargs` of the `subparsers` argument, 'A...'.

I get the same thing if I create a positional argument with the same nargs:

```
In [393]: import argparse
In [394]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [395]: p.add_argument('foo',nargs=argparse.PARSER)
Out[395]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [396]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] foo ...

positional arguments:
  foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Note the `nargs` string in `Out[395]`.  `add_subparsers` creates a positional argument with 'A...' `nargs` value.

```
In [403]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [404]: p.add_subparsers(dest='foo', metavar='FOO')
Out[404]: _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices={}, help=None, metavar='FOO')
In [405]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] FOO ...

positional arguments:
  FOO

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

That `nargs` takes all the remaining strings while requiring at least one.  The `add_parser` lines add `choices` to that subparser Action.

In formatting its `usage` the main parser "knows nothing" about what the sub-parsers do.  To it, the `subparsers` argument is just another positional argument with `choices`.  The same applies when parsing.  It just does the `suparsers.__call__` with the remaining `argv` strings.  That in turn passes those to the chosen `parser`.